# Attempting to run QMAKE_POST_LINK or system() in pro file does not seem to do anything

Tags: qt, qmake

I have attempted append commands to the QMAKE_POST_LINK akin to:

```
system(del C:\Version\Version.txt)
QMAKE_POST_LINK += start ..\installer\create_installer.exe;
```

and neither of them seem to be called.  This is a very basic command I am testing before doing the more complex build commands I'd like to implement.

I have attempted rebuilding and cleaning the build before doing so to force re-linking but nothing seems to get these to be called.  I have researched the problem online and cannot find anything that requires anything else be added to the .pro file in QT and am at a loss.  These exact same commands work on my linux build but I cannot seem to get them to work on Windows in as simple of a manner.

Comment: Is it a problem with your back slashes?

Comment: I ran it with both and it didn't work with them being back or forward.  I ran these from the command line and they ran fine and I imagine that that is all that these do so it has to be they're either not being interpreted correctly or not being called in the first place.

Comment: Maybe they need to be escaped (`\\` instead of `\`), and/or in quotes? Try using a different command that doesn't need any slashes at all and see if that gets called.